# TypeScript compile error due to typings

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm using typescript 1.7.5, typings 0.6.9 and angular 2.0.0-beta.0.

How can I get rid of the typescript compile error messages `Duplicate identifier` due to typings definition files?

The `Duplicate identifier` error occurs in the definition files of the following directories:

```
node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts
node_modules/angular2/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts
node_modules/angular2/typings/zone/zone.d.ts
typings/browser/ambient/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts
typings/browser/ambient/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts
typings/browser/ambient/karma/karma.d.ts
typings/browser/ambient/zone.js/zone.js.d.ts
```

What's the compiler doing in `node_modules/angular2` directory since I excluded it in `tsconfig.json`?

[I also posted this question on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7369)

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

They are gone if I change the `exclude` part of `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
]
```

But then after adding the following I get again the same `Duplicate identifier` compile errors:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

typings.json

```
{
  "name": "example-mean-app-client",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts#4de74cb527395c13ba20b438c3a7a419ad931f1c",
    "es6-promise": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts#830e8ebd9ef137d039d5c7ede24a421f08595f83",
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#4de74cb527395c13ba20b438c3a7a419ad931f1c",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#dd638012d63e069f2c99d06ef4dcc9616a943ee4",
    "karma": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/karma/karma.d.ts#02dd2f323e1bcb8a823269f89e0909ec9e5e38b5",
    "karma-jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/karma-jasmine/karma-jasmine.d.ts#661e01689612eeb784e931e4f5274d4ea5d588b7",
    "systemjs": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/systemjs/systemjs.d.ts#83af898254689400de8fb6495c34119ae57ec3fe",
    "zone.js": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/zone.js/zone.js.d.ts#9027703c0bd831319dcdf7f3169f7a468537f448"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As basarat alludes to, you can either change:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

to

```
"moduleResolution": "classic",
```

Or you can simply delete all of the duplicate typings from the typings folder. What's happening is that it's automatically importing all of the typings from the the node_modules folder of every `import` you do in your code. It's also importing the typings that are dependencies of the `browser.d.ts` file.

Comment: The setting "moduleResolution": "classic" gives other errors though due to not finding the modules you want to import.
I was not aware there were duplicate typings in "node_modules/angular2/typing" and "typings" directory. Deleting duplicate typings solved the problem

Comment: Has this been resolved? I'm encountering the same problem. I've been at it for a week now and none of the solutions have been helpful.

Comment: If you're having the exact same problem, then the issue was that he had installed some typings that were already included with Angular 2. This caused duplicates. The resolution was to uninstall the duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

For me, choosing either 'browser' or 'main' (depending on your application: front end or back end) and excluding the other one in `tsconfig.json` worked:

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: Can someone expand on this?  Is the solution provided appropriate for the general case using Angular2?

Answer (score 3):

> What's the compiler doing in node_modules/angular2 directory since I excluded it in tsconfig.json

Its looking at npm modules becuase of `"moduleResolution": "node",` but *only* the files that are imported (without the exclude it would look at *all* the files).